# Performance penalty of putting all records in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, azure-sql-database

I'm setting up an Azure SQL database to load about 1M rows a day.

I'm planning on loading all the data into one table with the following structure:

```
TAG_NAME | START_DATETIME | END_DATETIME | READING | READING_UOM | INTERVAL_SECS (computed column)
```

Each (TAG_NAME, START_DATETIME, END_DATETIME) are unique. So the following case is possible:

```
TAG_NAME | START_DATETIME | END_DATETIME      | READING | READING_UOM | INTERVAL_SECS (computed column)
X | 2020-01-01 01:00:00 | 2020-01-01 02:00:00 | 9.8     | m3          | 3600
X | 2020-01-01 01:00:00 | 2020-01-02 02:00:00 | 232.1   | m3          | 90000
```

I'm planning to create indexes on TAG_NAME, START_DATETIME and END_DATETIME.

From there I will create views. For example a view that pulls all the month-long readings for tags X, Y and Z.

Then another view that pulls the minute-readings for tags X, Y and D.

And so on..

So my question is, is there a performance impact on loading everything into one table? Should I divide the inputs into 'minute', 'hour', 'month', etc tables?

Comment: I don't see where "minute", "hour", and "month" are in your table.  Can you clarify the question.

Comment: From a design standpoint, this table doesn't look like it needs to be normalized. However, your example doesn't show a unique value for tag_name, etc.. Are you saying that the tag_name, etc, represent an identifier? If so, yeah, you may see performance enhancements by putting them in a separate table. Reduced storage, narrower foreign keys (because you can make it into an artificial key) all that ought to enhance performance.

Comment: Does all of the data change from one day to the next?  If not, there would be a significant performance benefit from only importing rows that have been modified or added

Comment: @GordonLinoff This are measurements that have a start and an end. Some of them last a minute, others a month, others a random time. So I could load them into different tables based on the measurement duration.

Comment: @GrantFritchey All the tags are unique and stored in another table together with the Asset they belong to, default UOM and other properties of the tags. I'm using the TAG_NAME as a key so that other people that might want to explore this table can understand it. Is the performance hit of using a long key too bad?

Comment: @Plato77 The data mostly doesn't change once loaded, I will be appending ~1M new values a day

Comment: How long are you going to keep the data for? After a year you will have 365M rows, which will not be fast.

Comment: @Alex at a minimum 10 years... Do you think that using an INT TAG_ID will make it faster to query?

Comment: The longer the key, the fewer rows stored on a page, so the greater the index depth. Yeah, it will impact performance. Now, for any given single row lookup will a CHAR(50) perform worse than an INT? Probably not enough to make a huge difference. Now, multiply it by millions of rows and millions of lookups, not even talking scans, and yeah, huge impact.

Answer (score 0):

As what @Grant Fritchey said the longer the key, the fewer rows stored on a page, so the greater the index depth. When the index come to be too large, it will impact performance.

1. Due to the rapid growth of data, I think you should divide the fact table into several tables, such as active table and historical archive table,distinguish by year.
2. You can consider about using [columnstore indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#what-is-a-columnstore-index) to compress data and improve [query performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-query-performance?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [date dimension table](https://radacad.com/do-you-need-a-date-dimension#:%7E:text=Date%20Dimension%20is%20a%20table,%2C%20no%20more%2C%20no%20less!&text=Columns%20will%20be%20normally%20all,used%20many%20times%20after%20it.) configured with whatever specific columns you may need for slicing and grouping your data.  If you only need Year, Month, and Day numbers, then that's all your date dimension would need.  But, if you need Hours, Minutes, Weeks, Quarters, or anything else, you can include those columns in the date dimension table too.

Indexing on the date dimension is easy and quick, since the row count is small.

Then, your fact table above would have FK relationships to the date dimension table for your START_DATETIME and END_DATETIME.